# Execute command with relative path inside Inline script

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I've the following code to execute parallels command in powershell

```
workflow Test-Workflow {
    
    $Sites = "Param1", "Param2", "Param3"
    
    ForEach -Parallel ($site in $Sites) {
        Parallel {
            InlineScript { C:\MyScriptsFolder\Script.ps1 -siteName $using:Sites}
        }
    }
}

Test-Workflow
```

I would like to execute my script with a relative path, instead of full path. But If I try to execute as

`InlineScript { ..\Script.ps1 -siteName $using:Sites}`

I got the error

`e term ..\Script.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

How can I use relative paths with InlineScript?

Thanks

Comment: The dots should be separated `. .\Script.ps1` if you want to dot source your script. Otherwise if you to just execute it use only 1 dot

Comment: As aside using relative paths is prone to failure. And `workflow` is usually not the best multithreading alternative available in PoweShell

Comment: Which other alternative can I use? Thanks!

Comment: For execution in parallel threads, use `Start-ThreadJob` in Windows PowerShell (requires `Install-Module ThreadJob`), and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel` in PowerShell (Core) 7+

Comment: If you're on Windows PowerShell and can't install the module, you can get parallel threads via multiple runspaces using the PowerShell SDK, but that's significantly more complex. Note that workflows are obsolescent, as evidenced by the fact that they weren't included in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)